# Which language should I prefer working with if I want to use the Fast Artificial Neural Network Library (FANN)?

Tags: neural-network

I am working on reducing dimentionality of a set of (Boolean) vectors with both the number and dimentionality of vectors tending to be of the order of 10^5-10^6 using autoencoders. Hence even though speed is not of essence (it is supposed to be a pre-computation for a clustering algorithm) but obviously one would expect that the computations take a reasonable amount of time. Seeing how the library itself was written in c++ would it be a good idea to stick to it or to code in Java (Since the rest of the code is written in Java)? Or would it not matter at all?

Answer (score 0):

That question is difficult to answer. It depends on:

- How computationally demanding will be your code? If the hard part is done by the library and your code is only to generate the input and post-process the output, Java would be a valid choice. Compare it to Matlab: The language is very slow but the built-in algorithms are super-fast.
- How skilled are you (or your team, or your future students) in Java and C++. Consider learning C++ takes a lot of time. If you have only a small scaled project, it could be easier to buy a bigger machine or wait two days instead of one, to get the results.
- Have you legacy code in one of the languages you want to couple or maybe re-use?

Overall, I would advice you to set up a benchmark example in whatever language you like more. Then give it a try. If the speed is ok, stick to it. If you wait to long, think about alternatives (new hardware, parallel execution, different language).

Comment: Hi,
1) Like I mentioned I intend to train an autoencoder neural network using the library with the runner program just building the neural network and running it.
2) I'm equally skilled at Java and C++
For prototyping(as a proof of concept) I'm going to use my own laptop, so it's kinda hard to get new hardware.
Also the official website for fannj says that that "Use FannJ if you have an existing ANN from the FANN project that you would like to access from Java. There are several GUI tools that will help you create and train an ANN.", which makes it seem like FANN can be used for accessing only

Comment: @Sahil1994: You can buy a new private laptop or switch to some workststation or small cluster. So hardware upgrade would be an easy option. 1) sounds like not much work in your code, so you could take Java. 2) So no help here neither. As there are no arguments left, you can freely choose.